# Is the equalizer using OpenSL in android 2.3 above?

Tags: android, android-ndk

The documentation says that the OpenSL is used in the equalizer.I am looking for some functions beyond those provided with the equalizer.Can any one let me know whether this can be achieved via the NDK?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Your question isn't very clear they way it's formulated right now.

Comment: @Michael...I just want to know whether I can do some functions beyond that provided by the equalizer using the NDK.